# Asp.net ajax DatePicker

Tags: asp.net, ajax, datepicker

Does somone knows where can I find an ajax DatePicker to use in Asp.net 2010?
I want it to work like the one in winforms.

TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ?

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Ajax Control Toolkit has the CalendarExtender and also jQuery date picker plugins.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

http://marcgrabanski.com/pages/code/jquery-ui-datepicker